# How do I add a command to my image which disappears if text on my page disappears?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making an HTML page to display information which is in numbers, I have the numbers being outputted into the page with another image which I want to be displayed under the output of numbers.

The text automatically disappears when it equals null/0, I want the image to disappear when the numbers disappear, I have updated the code by the help of a JS scripter however it did not solve my issue because the numbers in the code changes and the JS script only works once. The data is outputted into the page via an async function if that helps in any way.

a snippet of code (JS&HTML) :

```
<body>
    <img class="batset battery-img" src="img/bat.png"> <!-- this is the image I want to disappear when the numbers = 0.00 or have no output  -->
    <p id="pp-lable" class="text glow battery-output">0</p> <!--these numbers already disappear when they = 0.00 or have no output (these numbers change as it links to another JS which links to a pogram, so a JS that is shown in this snippet wont work as it does not repeat it self to detect the numbers that change-->
    <pre id="hit-count-lable" class="text-hit-count">0x100 0x50 0xMiss</pre> <!--this does not need to be modified or made to disappear it is fine as long as the numbers above do it-->

<script>
        let batteryIMG = document.querySelector('.battery-img')
        let output = document.querySelector('.battery-output');
        let batteryNum = document.querySelector('.battery-num')
        if(output.innerHTML === '0' || output.innerHTML === '' && 
        batteryNum.innerHTML === '' || batteryNum.innerHTML === '') {
        batteryIMG.style.display = 'none';
        output.style.display = 'none';
        batteryNum.style.display = 'none';
        }
</script>
```

UPDATE 1: I made the image and text disappear using this code but I don't know how to make them reappear and keep the script in a loop.

UPDATE 2: so I got help from a friend that found a loop that was in already built in the javascript and he just made 2 variables for the image and the numbers, and then inbuild the script which allowed the image to disappear when the text = to 0. Thank you for everyone for contributing in the thread, I will now be closing off this thread as answered and giving the best answer to Mysterious Shadow as the code we implemented into the js was suggested by her.

```
<body>
    <img class="batset battery-img" src="img/bat.png"/> 
    <p id="pp-lable" class="text glow battery-num"></p> 
    <pre id="hit-count-lable" class="text-hit-count">0x100 0x50 0xMiss</pre> 

<script>
    /*currently not working*/
    let batteryIMG = document.querySelector('.battery-img') // battery
    let batteryNum = document.querySelector('.battery-num') // number in battery
    if(batteryNum.innerHTML === '' || batteryNum.innerHTML === '') {
    batteryIMG.style.display= 'none'
    batteryNum.style.display = 'none';
    }

    else {
    (batteryNum.innerHTML === '' || batteryNum.innerHTML === ''); {
    batteryIMG.style.display = 'none'
    batteryNum.style.display = 'none'; 

        }


}
```

[image]
this is what displays with the html page running

[image]
this is what displays when the output equals 0/null (I want the image to disappear with the numbers when they equal 0/null)

Comment: the better way to share the current code. according to your text I think you want to group the image box just use your image box position relative and for number use absolute css.

Comment: Is this on drawn on canvas, using img tag or as background and some tag? Can you share your code? without the code we can only guess.

Comment: the page I want you to check is rtpp.html which displays the information. this is the whole HTML file however rtpp.html displays that information,

Comment: & by the way, the data (numbers) that change is live data that changes every second or so..

Comment: You should include relevant snippet of code directly in the question, if possible minimal working example. Edit your question copy paste relevant code and use {} button to have proper syntax highlighting and indent, you can also prepare Codepen or JSFiddle demo. This is how you ask question on StackOverflow check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You have lot of code, you will never get answer and your question will probably be closed, BTW: just opened the file, quick pick and you have first error, you didn't closed `@keyframes`, so the syntax highlighting is just broken. Try to create simple example, remove everything that is not related to actual questions you're asking, if your question is about JavaScript and Canvas use proper tags and don't use CSS that is not relevant to the question. If you have more then one issue, separate those (with proper code snippets) and ask as separated questions.

Comment: As you can clearly see I have not spent years on this website as you have judging from your profile, don't expect me to know everything after joining a day ago lmao.

Comment: I don't expect anything, If I would expect anything I would just close as off topic, I explain you everything what you need to know how to ask question and how to use StackOverflow properly. I see that you're new, that's why I explain you everything, this is more then you usually get on SO, they just write to read the link I've sent and put on hold until the question is fixed.

Comment: You should learn how to ask question before you ask, if you want to do that, and you should you can read this article by Eric S. Raymond [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Also the link I've send about SO question [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please read those and edit your question because it will be closed otherwise, by community they need to vote to close the question.

Comment: As you can see the answer below which was sent to me works, however, the numbers in my code changes and the Javascript does not repeat itself, I just want a simple fix. & thank you for your advice, I'm going to edit the post and delete the tag 'CSS'.

Comment: There is no need for me to read that yet, I will save it and read it for the next time I post, this is because I'm halfway through fixing this, I'm happy for it to get closed however I just want someone to help me fix it :)

Comment: I've edited your question there was no need to delete the images, also if you use code snippets on SO don't use tripple backticks, this is not GitHub use 4 spaces indent or use button that will do that for you.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand this, is this your code? it look like the code from the answer from before you posted link to your code.

Comment: Yes, it is, this was edited by me today. I have implemented the JS she recommended that would solve this issue and it worked but the script doesn't repeat itself to check if the number '0' increases to a higher amount.

Comment: I suggest to don't check the value of innerHTML in if, use proper variable that will hold the value of the battery and compare that, this will make things easier. Separate the code that test the variable from the code that update the DOM (by update I mean the code that increase the battery counter) hold the state in variable.

Comment: I would love to but I have 0 to no knowledge in JS, which is why it is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using Javascript to manipulate the DOM. For this example, it is relatively simple to accomplish in Javascript.

```
let batteryIMG = document.querySelector('.battery-img') // battery
let output = document.querySelector('.battery-output');// bottom most number
let batteryNum = document.querySelector('.battery-num') // number in battery

if(output.innerHTML === '' || output.innerHTML === '0' && batteryNum.innerHTML === '' || batteryNum.innerHTML === '0') {
  batteryIMG.style.display = 'none'
  output.style.display = 'none';
  batteryNum.style.display = 'none';

}
```

and heres a link to a codepen I did that shows this in action. Just change the numbers to 0 or blank to see it work. 
https://codepen.io/Fairy121/pen/dyYoRVM

Comment: How do I link the image to the  JS script?

Comment: So I tried implementing the JS into the html and I set the class of the img to img-battery and it didn't work, I also did it without the class... could you leave some sort of contact so I can send you the code and you can check if you have time

Comment: Your description was a bit difficult to understand, so that might be why it didnt work. You can email me at RachaelConcessio@gmail.com and I can take a look at it

Comment: It is pretty simple on what I want to do sorry for making it sound difficult, I just want the image to disappear when the numbers disappear. The numbers disappear when they equal to 0.00pp/have no output information. I have sent you an email. with the code.

Comment: can you check this, I have checked it and it doesn't work for some reason. I have sent you an email with the html code.

Comment: so if I input the number 0 into the JS like this  "if(output.innerHTML === '0' || output.innerHTML === '' && batteryNum.innerHTML === '' || batteryNum.innerHTML === '0') {" then it hides the picture and the text but when the number increases to more than 0 the text and img does not show. However I have done some testing and when the numbers increase to more than 0 the code shows this "<p id="pp-lable" class="text glow battery-output battery-num">226.88pp</p>" this shows a number increase which is 226.88pp however it has a 'pp' at the end, I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: & by the way, the data (numbers) that change is live data that changes every second or so..

Answer (score 0):

First add an id to your image

Then add  document.getElementById('MyImg').classList.add('hidden') after the bracket as below

```
        let batteryIMG = document.querySelector('.battery-img')
        let output = document.querySelector('.battery-output');
        let batteryNum = document.querySelector('.battery-num')
        if(output.innerHTML === '0' || output.innerHTML === '' && 
        batteryNum.innerHTML === '' || batteryNum.innerHTML === '') {
        document.getElementById('MyImg').classList.add('hidden')  // Add this line
        batteryIMG.style.display = 'none';
        output.style.display = 'none';
        batteryNum.style.display = 'none';
        }
```

Comment: this code works but it only works once, when the number becomes 0 the script makes the image disappear but when it increases to more than 0 it doesn't reappear. btw this text is live so it increases and decreases in live time without me having to refresh the page.

Comment: You can add the same line in your code where the number changes from 0 to something but change the word add with remove as below document.getElementById('MyImg').classList.remove('hidden')

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, the live data that comes to the page is done via an async function, this is what I have learnt from digging deeper into the code if it helps in any way...

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/ulq41y1bci2aymr/html.zip/file this is the directory of the webpage, the page that consists of this information is rtpp.html